# Link list in Ada

Tags: ada, gnat

I am new to Ada, I am doing linked list program and facing some strange issue
When i am adding node in list i can traverse to last node and print node value,
but when i am traversing to actually print values program exits, below is my code,

```
with 
Ada.Text_IO,
Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada;

procedure Ada_Link_List is

type Node;
type Node_Ptr is access Node;
type Node is
    record
        Id: Integer;
        Value: Integer;
        Next: Node_Ptr;
    end record;
        procedure Print_List(Firt_Node: in Node_Ptr) is
        Temp_Node : Node_Ptr;
        begin
            if Firt_Node = null then
                Ada.Text_IO.Put("List is Empty");
                Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
            end if;
            Temp_Node := Firt_Node;
            Ada.Text_IO.Put("List -----");
            while Temp_Node.Next /= null loop
                Ada.Text_IO.Put("while -----");
                Integer_Text_IO.Put(Temp_Node.Id);
                Integer_Text_IO.Put(Temp_Node.Value);
                Temp_Node := Temp_Node.Next;
                Ada.Text_IO.Put("Printing node");
                Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
            end loop;

        end Print_List;


        procedure Add_Node(Id: Integer; Value: Integer; New_Node: in out Node_Ptr) is
        Temp_Node : Node_Ptr;
        begin
            if New_Node = null then
                New_Node := new Node'(Id,Value,null);
                Ada.Text_IO.Put("Adding Head node");
                Integer_Text_IO.Put(New_Node.Id);
                Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
            else
                Temp_Node := New_Node;
                while Temp_Node.Next /= null loop
                        Temp_Node := Temp_Node.Next;
                end loop;

                Ada.Text_IO.Put("Adding Next node");
                Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
                Temp_Node := new Node'(Id,Value,null);
            end if;
        end Add_Node;

    Head_Node : Node_Ptr := null;

    begin
        Add_Node(1,1,Head_Node);
        Add_Node(2,2,Head_Node);
        Add_Node(3,3,Head_Node);
        Add_Node(4,4,Head_Node);
        Add_Node(5,5,Head_Node);
        Print_List(Head_Node);
        Add_Node(6,6,Head_Node);
        Ada.Text_IO.Put("*** Exit ***");

    end Ada_Link_List;
```

### Help me with desired output that i want to print values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never really adding nodes.
All this does is creating a memory leak:

```
Temp_Node := new Node'(Id,Value,null);
```

I think you mean:

```
Temp_Node.Next := new Node'(Id,Value,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier and maybe more elegant using recursion

```
with 
  Ada.Text_IO,
  Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada;

procedure Ada_Link_List is

    type Node;
    type Node_Ptr is access Node;
    type Node is record
      Id: Integer;
      Value: Integer;
      Next: Node_Ptr;
    end record;

    procedure Print_List(Node: in Node_Ptr) is
    begin
      if Node /= null then
        Integer_Text_IO.Put(Node.Id);
        Integer_Text_IO.Put(Node.Value);
        Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
        Print_List(Node.Next);
      end if;
    end Print_List;

    procedure Append_Node(Id: Integer; Value: Integer; New_Node: in out Node_Ptr) is
    begin
      if New_Node = null then
        New_Node := new Node'(Id,Value,null);
        Ada.Text_IO.Put("Adding Head node");
        Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
      else
        if New_Node.Next /= null then
          Append_Node(Id, Value, New_Node.Next);
        else
          Ada.Text_IO.Put("Adding Next node");
          Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
          New_Node.Next := new Node'(Id, Value, null);
        end if;
      end if;
    end Append_Node;

    Head : Node_Ptr := null;

begin
    Append_Node(1, 1, Head);
    Append_Node(2, 2, Head);
    Append_Node(3, 3, Head);
    Append_Node(4, 4, Head);
    Append_Node(5, 5, Head);
    Print_List(Head);
    Append_Node(6, 6, Head);
    Print_List(Head);
end Ada_Link_List;
```